# Porting flash code to iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, flash, actionscript-2, unity-game-engine

I have flash code with AS2 scripts. It is a slot machine game and I want to port it to Android and iOS .Since it is a slot machine game UI aren't going to be a priority in choosing the technology I code in. I can very well create separate UI's in android and iOS and hook them up with a plugin from another language.However, I want to re use as much code from AS2,Since Most of the code contains logic for the slot machine and Bingo game. I would like to know how I can go about this. Should I go for unity 3D , Oracle ADF , Corona or any other IDE that will be useful. Or should I convert AS2 script to C code and use that as a plugin in both Android and iOS ? Or any other option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Scaleform Mobile](http://gameware.autodesk.com/usage/casual) that might work well for you. You can use AS2 code and it deploys to mobile. Scaleform uses their own runtime but it integrates with the Flash toolchain. We use the Unity3D plugin and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I have some kind experience with Scaleform for Unity plug-in and I also think
that it is the best solution 
for you needs (no matter Scaleform for Unity plug-in or Scaleform mobile).

In Scaleform you will able to leave most of the code base on AS side.

But Scaleform is advanced library with non-friendly documentation, therefore before you will able make you work, you needed to have some С++/C knowledge for bootstrapping skeleton app.